# Connection to Azure ServiceBus without proxy

Tags: azure, proxy, servicebus

I am trying to use to open a connection to the Azure servicebus subscription. In app.config I turn off proxy

```
    <system.net>
            <defaultProxy enabled="false"/>
    </system.net>
```

When I trying to call subscriptionClient.Receive() I getting
NullReferenceException and stack:

```
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.WebStream.ConfigureProxy(System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = {System.Net.HttpWebRequest}, Microsoft.ServiceBus.WebStream.ProxyAuthMode mode = None) + 0x87 bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.WebStream.CreateSession(out System.Uri endpointLocation1 = null, out System.Uri endpointLocation2 = null) + 0x2ab bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.WebStream.Connect() + 0x38 bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.WebStream.WebStream(System.Uri factoryEndpointUri = {System.Uri}, string webSocketRole = "messaging", bool useHttpsMode = false, Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.EventTraceActivity activity = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.EventTraceActivity}) + 0x217 bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.WebSocketConnection.WebSocketConnection(System.Uri factoryEndpointUri = {System.Uri}, string webSocketRole = "messaging", int asyncReadBufferSize = 8192, bool useHttpsMode = false, Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.EventTraceActivity activity = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.EventTraceActivity}) + 0x42 bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.WebSocketOnewayConnectionInitiator.Connect(System.Uri uri = {System.Uri}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}) + 0x72 bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.WebSocketOnewayConnectionInitiator.BeginConnect(System.Uri uri = {System.Uri}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnectionAsyncResult}) + 0x3d bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.BufferedConnectionInitiator.BeginConnect(System.Uri uri = {System.Uri}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnectionAsyncResult}) + 0x4c bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnectionAsyncResult.OpenUsingNewConnection() + 0xe5 bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnectionAsyncResult.Begin() + 0xb4 bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnectionAsyncResult.EstablishConnectionAsyncResult(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper parent = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0xb7 bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.BeginEstablishConnection(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0x4d bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OpenAsyncResult.OpenAsyncResult(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel duplexChannel = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0xe3 bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnBeginOpen(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0x4d bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult.InvokeOpen() + 0x8a bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult.OpenAsyncResult(System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject communicationObject = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0xbd bytes   
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.BeginOpen(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0x1fc bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.LayeredChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IDuplexSessionChannel>.OnBeginOpen(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0x49 bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult.InvokeOpen() + 0x8a bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult.OpenAsyncResult(System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject communicationObject = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.SocketConnectionChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IDuplexSessionChannel>.DuplexSessionChannel}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0xbd bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.BeginOpen(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0x1fc bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.OnBeginOpen(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult}) + 0x5a bytes 
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult.InvokeOpen() + 0x8a bytes  
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncResult.OpenAsyncResult(System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject communicationObject = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult}) + 0xbd bytes    
System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.BeginOpen(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult}) + 0x1fc bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult.GetAsyncSteps.AnonymousMethod__3(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult thisPtr = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult}, System.TimeSpan t = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback c = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object s = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult}) + 0x57 bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult>.EnumerateSteps(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult>.CurrentThreadType state = StartingThread) + 0xa0a bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult>.Start() + 0x5e bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.OnBeginCreateInstance(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}) + 0xcb bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.BeginGetInstance(System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}) + 0x1c6 bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.GetAsyncSteps.AnonymousMethod__1(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult thisPtr = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}, System.TimeSpan t = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback c = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object s = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}) + 0x4d bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.EnumerateSteps(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.CurrentThreadType state = StartingThread) + 0x7e5 bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.Start() + 0x5e bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.BeginRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}) + 0x9b bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.GetAsyncSteps.AnonymousMethod__9(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult thisPtr = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}, System.TimeSpan t = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback c = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object s = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}) + 0x5b bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.EnumerateSteps(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.CurrentThreadType state = StartingThread) + 0x7e5 bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.Start() + 0x5e bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.BeginRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}) + 0x86 bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.GetAsyncSteps.AnonymousMethod__3(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult thisPtr = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}, System.TimeSpan t = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback c = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object s = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}) + 0x58 bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.EnumerateSteps(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.CurrentThreadType state = Callback) + 0xa0a bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.StepCallback(System.IAsyncResult result = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.AsyncWaiter}) + 0x1c6 bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(System.IAsyncResult result = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.AsyncWaiter}) + 0x146 bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.TryComplete(bool didCompleteSynchronously = false, System.Exception exception = null) + 0x204 bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.Complete(bool didCompleteSynchronously = false, System.Exception e = null) + 0x3c bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.AsyncWaiter.Signal(System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel result = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel}, System.Exception completeException = null) + 0x55 bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CompleteWaiters(System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel singleton = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RedirectContainerSessionChannel}, System.Exception completeException = null) + 0x199 bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.EndGetInstance(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult}) + 0x1e3 bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.GetAsyncSteps.AnonymousMethod__2(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult thisPtr = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult}, System.IAsyncResult r = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.SharedChannel<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.CreateChannelAsyncResult}) + 0x3b bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.EnumerateSteps(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.CurrentThreadType state = StartingThread) + 0xc24 bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult>.Start() + 0x5e bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory<System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestSessionChannel>.RequestSessionChannel.BeginRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message = {System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult}) + 0x9b bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.BeginReceiveCommand(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext trackingContext = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext}, int messageCount = 1, System.TimeSpan serverWaitTime = {System.TimeSpan}, System.TimeSpan timeout = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult}) + 0x1b5 bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult.GetAsyncSteps.AnonymousMethod__26(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult thisPtr = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult}, System.TimeSpan t = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback c = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object s = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult}) + 0x87 bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult>.EnumerateSteps(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult>.CurrentThreadType state = StartingThread) + 0xa0a bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsyncResult>.Start() + 0x5e bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageReceiver.OnBeginTryReceive(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext trackingContext = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext}, int messageCount = 1, System.TimeSpan serverWaitTime = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback callback = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object state = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult}) + 0x1df bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult.GetAsyncSteps.AnonymousMethod__62(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult thisPtr = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult}, System.TimeSpan t = {System.TimeSpan}, System.AsyncCallback c = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}}, object s = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult}) + 0x60 bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult>.EnumerateSteps(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult>.CurrentThreadType state = Synchronous) + 0xa0a bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.RetryReceiveAsyncResult>.RunSynchronously() + 0x5a bytes 
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.OnTryReceive(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext trackingContext = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext}, int messageCount = 1, System.TimeSpan serverWaitTime = {System.TimeSpan}, out System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage> messages = null) + 0x7c bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.TryReceive(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext trackingContext = {Microsoft.ServiceBus.Tracing.TrackingContext}, int messageCount = 1, System.TimeSpan serverWaitTime = {System.TimeSpan}, out System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage> messages = null) + 0x131 bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.TryReceive(int messageCount = 1, System.TimeSpan serverWaitTime = {System.TimeSpan}, out System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage> messages = null) + 0x3a bytes   
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.TryReceive(System.TimeSpan serverWaitTime = {System.TimeSpan}, out Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage message = null) + 0x57 bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.Receive(System.TimeSpan serverWaitTime = {System.TimeSpan}) + 0x3a bytes    
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageReceiver.Receive() + 0x4b bytes  
Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll!Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SubscriptionClient.Receive() + 0x45 bytes   
Program.Main(string[] args = {string[5]}) Line 42 + 0xb bytes   C#
```

I think that trouble in

```
private void ConfigureProxy(HttpWebRequest request, ProxyAuthMode mode)
{
    IWebProxy proxy = request.Proxy;
    Uri uriPrefix = request.Proxy.GetProxy(request.RequestUri);
```

When proxy is off request.Proxy has null value.

Do you know how I can workaround this. And where I can submit bug to ServiceBus team?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the SB team, I'll have this reviewed. Which version of the ServiceBus assembly are you using there?

That said, leaving the defaultProxy enabled means nothing but falling back to the WinINet (IE) default options and if you have no proxy there, you'll be good.

Comment: Hello!
I'm using Assembly Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version 2.1.0.0. File version: 2.1.30521.0
This post http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/Dec/14/Slow-Http-client-calls-from-ASPNET-20-Make-sure-you-check-your-Proxy-Settings explains why you should change default settings for defaultProxy